# ValueError: Attempted relative import in non-package - relative import in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

The folder directory is:

```
server/
    |_entities.py
    |_config.py
```

In my entities.py file, I have the following:

```
from .config import config
```

But when I debug, it results in the following problem:

```
File "entities.py", line 14, in <module>
from .config import config
ValueError: Attempted relative import in non-package
```

Comment: Please translate your question to English. Otherwise https://pt.stackoverflow.com might be a better choice.

Comment: Read up on [Tutorial - 6.4. Packages](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#packages)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you have an `__init__.py` in the server directory. This is an empty file required to make Python treat directories containing the file as packages.

Then try `from server.config import config`

Server is the top level name of your package.

From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#packages)

> Packages are a way of structuring Python’s module namespace by using
> “dotted module names”. For example, the module name A.B designates a
> submodule named B in a package named A

You should also consider renaming the variable `config` to something else so that it's not confused with the file called config.